# What is wrong in this JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON string looks like this,

> [{"id" : "38","heading" : "Can you
>   also figure out how to get me back the
>   10 hours I
>   sp.....","description" : "Im having a
>   very similar problem with the Login
>   control - again it always generates a
>   default style containing
>   border-collapse - only in this case
>   .....","img_url" :
>   "~/EventImages/EventImages1274014884460.jpg","catogory"
>   : "News","doe" : "15-05-2010 "},
>
> {"id" : "40","heading" : "How to
>   remove the border of each row (from
>   the gridview cont.....","description"
>   : "How to remove the border of each
>   row (from the gridview control). ? I
>   set borderWidth to 0, and the borders
>   are not displayed with IE, but the top
>   a.....","img_url" :
>   "~/EventImages/EventImages1274028613023.jpg","catogory"
>   : "News","doe" : "15-05-2010 "},
>
> {"id" : "41","heading" : "Realmac
>   Software | How to fix FancyZoom popup?
>   (pops up behi.....","description" :
>   "The first thing we need is an options
>   dialog, not only to make it easier for
>   the user, but also because later we
>   will want to launch this dialog from
>   .....","img_url" :
>   "~/EventImages/EventImages1274037688120.jpg","catogory"
>   : "News","doe" : "15-05-2010 "},
>
> {"id" : "42","heading" : "hi jacon
>   
> dsadddaddddddddddddddd","description" : "hi jacon 
>  This is a little
>   messy because the clientHeight/Width
>   properties can mean different things
>   in different browsers, and even
>   different thi.....","img_url" :
>   "~/EventImages/EventImages1274041211533.jpg","catogory"
>   : "News","doe" : "15-05-2010 "}

But get the error,

`unterminated string literal`....

**EDIT:**

I used this but it didn't work,

```
 var newjson = cfreturn( """" & ToString( HfJsonValue ).ReplaceAll( "(['""\\\/\n\r\t]{1})", "\\$1" ) & """" ) ;
 var jsonObj = eval('(' + newjson + ')');
```

Error: `missing ) after argument list`

Source Code:

```
var newjson = cfreturn( """" & ToString( HfJsonValue ).ReplaceAll( "(['""\\\/\n\r\t]{1})", "\\$1" ) & """" );
```

EDIT:

There is a `'` mark in JSON string that causes the problem... any suggestion

Comment: does any of the content include quotes or double quotes? are they escaped?

Comment: Are you absolutely positive that there is no `'` in the first "Im" in the `description` field? Depending on where you look up the JSON string (Firebug, for example) it might be cleaned for you, so you never see the problem...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is wrong in this json string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847228/what-is-wrong-in-this-json-string)

Comment: Check that you are using ASCII `"` and not some UTF-8 or other quotation marks. Because this seams good to me...

Comment: and does it contain new lines? I noticed quite a few but not sure if this was because of pasting or something else.

Comment: vote unclose: the other question has been deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around with [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/), I found the following two problems:

1. Newlines need to be escaped with `\\n`.
2. You're missing the terminal `]`.

Comment: By fixing the line breaks and adding the closing `]` it parses correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely to be caused by an unescaped linebreak in there somewhere. In the example, there's linebreaks everywhere, though I assume they were added for formatting purposes.

If you do have linebreaks, either replace them with "\n" or put "\" at the end of the line:

```
var x = "multi \n line \n string";
var y = "multi\
line\
string";

// this causes the "unterminated string literal" error.
var z = "multi
line
string";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to escape all special characters including `\n` which is generally the cause of such error.

Take a look at this [blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/557-JSON-Unterminated-String-Literal-Error.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are getting the JSON is generating invalid JSON.

Cleaning it up is less than trivial and is approaching the problem from the wrong direction.

Solve the problem at the source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var newjson = "{'id' : '38','heading' : 'Can you also figure out how to get me back the 10 "
        + "hours I sp.....','description' : 'Im having a very similar problem with the "
        + "Login control - again it always generates a default style containing border "
        + " -collapse -only in this case .....','img_url' : '~/EventImages/"
        + "EventImages1274014884460.jpg','catogory' : 'News','doe' : '15-05-2010 '}";

        var jsonObj = eval('(' + newjson + ')');

        alert(jsonObj.id);
        alert(jsonObj.heading);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

That stray quote mark should be escaped automatically. Are you generating the json yourself? If so I would strongly recommend using a json library for whatever language you are working with to generate it for you, otherwise you will keep running into increasingly obscure versions of this problem.